# Runtime Error after exporting a Web Service to a different environment

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, windows-server-2008

I have been developing a Web Service for some time now on my Eclipse IDE and after I finished it I exported it to a Server running Windows server 2008 R2.  After deploying it successfully I run into runtime errors :

16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory.newInstance(ServiceFactory.java:63)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jsp.GetDocuments_jsp._jspService(GetDocuments_jsp.java:86)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
16:03:39,358 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This happens when I try to access the Web Methods, in this example GetDocuments is the Web Method.  The client is using JSP to create Binding Stubs to communication with the Service.  These stubs are automatic generate by the Eclipse IDE.  I don't know too much else about Web Services or how look into these problem further as it the errors do not point to any real class in my project.

My big question would be why I received no errors until I exported the project.  I was thinking that it might be an issue with THe JRE or compiler but they are the same on both platforms.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I guess you have a version conflict here. Did you provide your own version of a jbossws library, jboss-jaxrpc.jar or javaee-api-*.jar?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  The Libraries for both environmens should be the same but I will check to make sure and get back momentarily.

Comment: That was the issue, after I made sure the libraries were the same it went away.

Comment: I'll add an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory` is most likely contained in either `jboss-jaxrpc.jar` or `javaee-api-*.jar` (* being the version).

`org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceFactoryImpl` is contained in a jbossws library.

Thus you have to make sure that your JBoss uses compatible versions of those libraries, which seems to be the case in your eclipse setup.

For future readers: the solution was to make sure that the libraries used by JBoss matched those used by Eclipse which apparently were of compatible versions.